# SharePoint Designer, Unable to open workflow due to Visio

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, visio

I have SharePoint designer workflow (Online), I opened that workflow with Visio in my machine (didn't make any modification) and it was perfectly working fine but now when I am opening the same workflow on another machine (Where Visio is not installed), it's not working.

Anyone has any idea, how to de-attach both?

Below is the error which I am facing.
[image]

When I am trying to restore the previous version by navigating to **All Files >> Workflows**, there also i am unable to see this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 workflows are not listed in All Files->Workflows, and there is no OOB way to restore 2013 workflow to previous version.

For your situation, I suggest you create a new SharePoint 2013 workflow and design it like the old workflow, then use the new workflow instead of the old one.